# Strange Results from a Timestamp Calculation PHP

Tags: php, time

I'm working with php timestamps to develop a calendar of events page.

On the Calendar page, I've written a function to determine a few things right away such as:

- Month the user has selected (default to the current timestamp's month)
- The First day of that month (as determined thusly):

```
$first_of_month = strtotime(date('m',time()).'/01/'.date('Y',time()));
```

Now - using the the first day of the month, I must determine the most recent Sunday prior to that day (the Calendar starts on Sundays), so I run it through this:

```
date('m/d/Y--D-w',($first_of_month - (date('w',$first_of_month)*86400)))
```

the problem is it's not returning what I would expect.

Currently we're in April, 2016. Day 1 of April returns 5 when run through the date('w') format. So, 5 days back from that Friday should be day 0 (Sunday). But I get Saturday.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Robbie - couldn't get the code highlighter to work properly...

Comment: sure about the servers timezone

Comment: No problem - it's tricky within lists ;) [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3793/243324)

Comment: Server is one hour behind my local,  but as I said the date('w') returns 5, (Friday) thus, first day -( 5×86400) I'd expect to return Saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the 1 hour offset put you past midnight (into tomorrow)? I'd recommend you double check your server offset: `date_default_timezone_get();`

If it is wrong, use `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')` (obviously replacing 'America/Los_Angeles' as appropriate. [php: date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

As long as that's correct you could get the last Sunday by using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on `$first_of_month`:

```
date('m/d/Y--D-w' ,strtotime('last Sunday',$first_of_month));
```

Comment: An elegant solution and timezone shouldn't matter because in the original time that I'm setting (first_of_month) I truncate the timestamp and use only the date. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHPs date word parser is extremely powerful. If you're looking for the last Sunday of last month, you can just ask!

```
$date = new DateTime();
if($date->format('w') != 0) {
    $date->modify('last Sunday of last month');
}
```

See ideone here: https://ideone.com/sWsxPW

Comment: If I were after the Last Sunday of Last month that would be very helpful - but if the 1st of a month lands on a Sunday I want the modifier to be:
first_day - (0*86400). meaning it would return itself.

Comment: You can wrap in a simple condition for that. See my updated answer.